# hang and/or segfault when using boost::threads from matlab, not when called directly

Tags: c++, multithreading, matlab, boost, mex

**What the problem was, in case people have a similar problem:** after some discussions with Mathworks support, it turned out to be a conflict between the system boost and Matlab's shipped boost libraries: when I compiled with system boost headers and linked with (older) Matlab boost libraries, it segfaulted. When I compiled and dynamically linked with system boost but then it dynamically loaded the Matlab boost libraries, it hung forever.

Static linking to system boost works, as does downloading the correct headers for the version of boost that Matlab ships with and compiling with those. Of course, the Mac builds of Matlab don't have version numbers in their filenames, though the Linux and supposedly Windows builds do. R2011b uses boost 1.44, for reference.

---

I have some multithreaded code that works fine when it's compiled directly, but segfaults and/or deadlocks when it's called from a Matlab `mex` interface. I don't know whether the different environment is revealing a flaw in my code, or what, but I can't figure it out....

I'm running this on three machine configurations (though there are several of the CentOS boxes):

- OSX 10.7, g++ 4.2, boost 1.48, Matlab R2011a (clang++ 2.1 also works for standalone, haven't tried to get mex to use clang)
- ancient CentOS, g++ 4.1.2, boost 1.33.1 (debug and not debug), Matlab R2010b
- ancient CentOS, g++ 4.1.2, boost 1.40 (no debug versions installed), Matlab R2010b

Here's a pared-down version with this behavior.

```
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/utility.hpp>

#ifndef NO_MEX
#include "mex.h"
#endif

class Worker : boost::noncopyable {
    boost::mutex &jobs_mutex;
    std::queue<size_t> &jobs;

    boost::mutex &results_mutex;
    std::vector<double> &results;

    public:

    Worker(boost::mutex &jobs_mutex, std::queue<size_t> &jobs,
           boost::mutex &results_mutex, std::vector<double> &results)
        :
            jobs_mutex(jobs_mutex), jobs(jobs),
            results_mutex(results_mutex), results(results)
    {}

    void operator()() {
        size_t i;
        float r;

        while (true) {
            // get a job
            {
                boost::mutex::scoped_lock lk(jobs_mutex);
                if (jobs.size() == 0)
                    return;

                i = jobs.front();
                jobs.pop();
            }

            // do some "work"
            r = rand() / 315.612;

            // write the results
            {
                boost::mutex::scoped_lock lk(results_mutex);
                results[i] = r;
            }
        }
    }
};

std::vector<double> doWork(size_t n) {
    std::vector<double> results;
    results.resize(n);

    boost::mutex jobs_mutex, results_mutex;

    std::queue<size_t> jobs;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        jobs.push(i);

    Worker w1(jobs_mutex, jobs, results_mutex, results);
    boost::thread t1(boost::ref(w1));

    Worker w2(jobs_mutex, jobs, results_mutex, results);
    boost::thread t2(boost::ref(w2));

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return results;
}

#ifdef NO_MEX
int main() {
#else
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray **plhs, int nrhs, const mxArray **prhs) {
#endif
    std::vector<double> results = doWork(10);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
        printf("%g ", results[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Note that on boost 1.48, I get the same behavior if I change the functor into a standard function and just pass `boost::ref`s to the mutexes/data as extra arguments to `boost::thread`. Boost 1.33.1 doesn't support this, though.

---

When I compile it directly, it always runs fine -- I've never seen it fail in any situation:

```
$ g++ -o testing testing.cpp -lboost_thread-mt -DNO_MEX
$ ./testing
53.2521 895008 5.14128e+06 3.12074e+06 3.62505e+06 1.48984e+06 320100 4.61912e+06 4.62206e+06 6.35983e+06
```

---

Running from Matlab, I've seen a lot of different behaviors after making different tweaks to the code and so on, though no changes that actually make any sense to me. But here's what I've seen with the exact code above:

- On OSX / boost 1.48:

  - If it's linked to a release-variant boost, I get a segfault trying to access a near-0 address inside of `boost::thread::start_thread`, being called from `t1`'s constructor.
  - If it's linked to a debug-variant boost, it hangs forever in the first `boost::thread::join`. I'm not entirely certain, but I think the worker threads have actually completed at this point (don't see anything in `info threads` that's obviously them).
- On CentOS / boost 1.33.1 and 1.40:

  - With release boost, I get a segfault in `pthread_mutex_lock`, being called from the `boost::thread::join` on `t1`.
  - With debugging boost, it hangs forever in `__lll_lock_wait` inside `pthread_mutex_lock` in the same place. As shown below, the worker threads have completed at this point.

I don't know how to do anything more with the segfaults, since they never occur when I have debugging symbols that can actually tell me what the null pointer is.

In the hanging-forever case, I seem to always get something like this if I'm stepping through in GDB:

```
99      Worker w1(jobs_mutex, jobs, results_mutex, results);
(gdb) 
100     boost::thread t1(boost::ref(w1));
(gdb) 
[New Thread 0x47814940 (LWP 19390)]
102     Worker w2(jobs_mutex, jobs, results_mutex, results);
(gdb) 
103     boost::thread t2(boost::ref(w2));
(gdb) 
[Thread 0x47814940 (LWP 19390) exited]
[New Thread 0x48215940 (LWP 19391)]
[Thread 0x48215940 (LWP 19391) exited]
105     t1.join();
```

That sure looks like both threads are complete before the call to `t1.join()`. So I tried adding a `sleep(1)` call in the "doing work" section between the locks; when I'm stepping through, the threads exit after the call to `t1.join()` and it still hangs forever:

```
106     t1.join();
(gdb)
[Thread 0x47814940 (LWP 20255) exited]
[Thread 0x48215940 (LWP 20256) exited]
# still hanging
```

If I `up` out to the `doWork` function, `results` is populated with the same results that the standalone version prints on this machine, so it looks like all that is going through.

I have no idea what's causing either of the segfaults or the crazy hanging-ness, or why it is that it always works outside Matlab and never inside, or why it's different with/without debugging symbols, and I have no idea how to proceed in figuring this out. Any thoughts?

---

At @alanxz's suggestion, I've run the standalone version of the code under valgrind's memcheck, helgrind, and DRD tools:

- On CentOS using valgrind 3.5, none of the tools give any non-suppressed errors.
- On OSX using valgrind 3.7:

  - Memcheck doesn't give any non-suppressed errors.
  - Helgrind crashes for me when run on any binary (including e.g. `valgrind --tool=helgrind ls`) on OSX, complaining about an unsupported instruction.
  - DRD gives over a hundred errors.

The DRD errors are pretty inscrutable to me, and though I've read the manual and so on, I can't make any sense of them. Here's the first one, on a version of the code where I commented out the second worker/thread:

```
Thread 2:
Conflicting load by thread 2 at 0x0004b518 size 8
   at 0x3B837: void boost::call_once<void (*)()>(boost::once_flag&, void (*)()) (in /usr/local/boost/boost_1_48_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread-mt-d.dylib)
   by 0x2BCD4: boost::detail::set_current_thread_data(boost::detail::thread_data_base*) (in /usr/local/boost/boost_1_48_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread-mt-d.dylib)
   by 0x2BA62: thread_proxy (in /usr/local/boost/boost_1_48_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread-mt-d.dylib)
   by 0x2D88BE: _pthread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
   by 0x2DBB74: thread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
Allocation context: Data section of r/local/boost/boost_1_48_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread-mt-d.dylib
Other segment start (thread 1)
   at 0x41B4DE: __bsdthread_create (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
   by 0x2B959: boost::thread::start_thread() (in /usr/local/boost/boost_1_48_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread-mt-d.dylib)
   by 0x100001B54: boost::thread::thread<boost::reference_wrapper<Worker> >(boost::reference_wrapper<Worker>, boost::disable_if<boost::is_convertible<boost::reference_wrapper<Worker>&, boost::detail::thread_move_t<boost::reference_wrapper<Worker> > >, boost::thread::dummy*>::type) (thread.hpp:204)
   by 0x100001434: boost::thread::thread<boost::reference_wrapper<Worker> >(boost::reference_wrapper<Worker>, boost::disable_if<boost::is_convertible<boost::reference_wrapper<Worker>&, boost::detail::thread_move_t<boost::reference_wrapper<Worker> > >, boost::thread::dummy*>::type) (thread.hpp:201)
   by 0x100000B50: doWork(unsigned long) (testing.cpp:66)
   by 0x100000CE1: main (testing.cpp:82)
Other segment end (thread 1)
   at 0x41BBCA: __psynch_cvwait (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
   by 0x3C0C3: boost::condition_variable::wait(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&) (in /usr/local/boost/boost_1_48_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread-mt-d.dylib)
   by 0x2D28A: boost::thread::join() (in /usr/local/boost/boost_1_48_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread-mt-d.dylib)
   by 0x100000B61: doWork(unsigned long) (testing.cpp:72)
   by 0x100000CE1: main (testing.cpp:82)
```

Line 66 is the construction of the thread, and 72 is the `join` call; there's nothing but comments in between. As far as I can tell, this is saying that there's a race between that part of the master thread and the worker thread's initialization...but I don't really understand how that's possible?

The rest of the output from DRD [is here](https://gist.github.com/1706984); I'm not getting anything out of it.

Comment: Have you tried running it under valgrind, [helgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html), or [DRD](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/drd-manual.html)?  That might reveal some clues about whats going on.

Comment: @alanxz Thanks for the suggestion, I wasn't aware of helgrind/DRD. I've added some details about what those say to the question. I get DRD errors on OSX, but have no idea what they mean, despite reading the manual and so on....

Comment: Did anyone try to set up the @rpath on Linux like environment? I currently have the same issue, I am thinking that the mex should do the proper isolation of its dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that's the simplest case that segfaults and/or hangs?  If the results from DRD do indicate a race condition just between thread construction and joining, it sounds like your code might not be at fault (especially since you don't actually use any `mex`-specific features, but just running under `mex` triggers the bug).

Maybe try just this version:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void doNothing() { return; }

void doWork() {
    boost::thread t1(doNothing);
    t1.join();
}

#ifdef NO_MEX
int main() {
#else
#include "mex.h"
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray **plhs, int nrhs, const mxArray **prhs) {
#endif
    doWork();
}
```

This definitely shouldn't segfault or hang either under `mex` or compiled directly - so if it does, it's not your bug, and if it doesn't, maybe you can progressively close the distance between your version and this one to find the bug-causing addition.

Comment: Yep, that version segfaults too. I guess mex and boost threads just don't work together. Time to report it as a bug and port to pthreads, I guess....

Answer (score 0):

There is a point of failure in your code: When any thread is delayed by more than 2 seconds, the `timed_lock` call in the lock constructor can time out, the mutex is *not* acquired, and you access the protected structure anyway. If you use timed mutexes, you'll have to test whether the lock actually locked the mutex or merely timed out. This can be checked by calling the locks' `owns_lock()` method.

I don't see any motivation for the timed mutexes here, and you mention "after taking out the timed thread stuff", but I still suspect this mutex timeout bug to be at fault here. Does this bug still occur when you replace `timed_mutex` with plain `mutex`?

Comment: I originally used plain `mutex`; the `timed_mutex` stuff was added after seeing the deadlock behavior. For some reason I thought `timed_mutex` threw an exception if it didn't acquire the lock, though I guess I don't know why I thought that. Also, when it segfaults, it happens immediately -- definitely not something that's happening after 2 seconds.

Comment: To be explicit: yes, I still get segfaults / hangs when I replace `timed_mutex` with a plain `mutex` (and remove the time argument and so on, obviously). I'm now seeing a consistency in the problem between my OSX Boost 1.48 machine and the CentOS Boost 1.33.1 machine that I didn't seem to have before, though...will investigate that a little more thoroughly and then edit the question.

Comment: I've fixed that problem and edited the question. It seems like the lock stuff wasn't the problem, since it segfaults before it gets there on OSX+new boost, and on CentOS+old boost the threads successfully complete (at least when I'm debugging them) but either crash or hang when asked to join.